# Return true if all the characters in the string are different

Tags: java

I want my code to return true if all the characters in the string are different but it returns true even if some of the characters are the same .For example in the string input the character 'r' is repeated three times and the method still returns true.What am I doing wrong?
My code:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
System.out.println(code("qrrrtyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm")); }
public static boolean code(String input)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
      {
      char temp=input.charAt(i);
      char x =input.charAt(i+1);
      if(temp!=x)
      {
     return true;
      }
     
      }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Hint: your code returns true as soon as it finds *any* pair of characters that aren't the same. (Note that you also never compare characters that aren't next to each other - consider what would happen with "aba".)

Comment: Yes ,it would still return true .I'm not sure how to check if all the characters are different.

Comment: The check that should abort the iteration is when you find two characters that are the same, you got that bit of logic reversed. You could do a double loop and compare every character i with every other character j. Or you could sort the string and now comparing adjacent letters is correct. Or you could stuff the contents of the string into a Set, if the resulting set has the same size as the string, the letters were unique...

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to check if all the characters are different."*  - How would you do it "by hand"?

Comment: Yes I have made a flowchart ,and I knew I had to make a simple change to this code but it just didn't come to mind

Answer (score 0):

Running through each line of the code, we can see that it is checking the two characters next to each other. The first two characters are "qr", since these are different the function returns true, and doesn't even look at the three r's in a row. For it to achieve what you asked in the question the code should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(code("qrrrtyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm")); 
}
public static boolean code(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { //I have changed it from 27, to input.length() as I assume you want it to work for any input
        for (int j = i+1; j < input.length(); j++) {
            if(input[i] == input[j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @UtkarshSahu I don't think I understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean code(String input)
{
    if (input.length > (26 or 52)) //depending if the string have upper case char or not, if you  are do not know which char could be there just put the max number of char or delete the line with return state
        return false;//if you have more than that number of character you for sure will have repetition due to pigeon hole principle
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
      for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++)
      {
         if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)) //check for all pairs to not to be the same
            return false; //if found at least one pair of identical 
      }
   
    return true;//if nothing found return true
}
```

Comment: What if there string contained digits?  Or punctuation characters? Or control characters?  Or Chinese characters?  Or ... emoji?

Comment: Although I like the idea, I don't know how useful the pigeon hole idea is, as it is very possible that they are using other characters, such as numbers, or literally any Unicode character.

Comment: if you are not sure about the numbers you can just put the max value of char

Answer (score -1):

Use a `Set` and return false as soon as something is present in the set, otherwise return true after cycling through the input string..

```
public boolean checkUniqueLetters(String inputString) {
    Set<String> letterSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (String letter : inputString.split("")) {
        if (letterSet.contains(letter)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            letterSet.add(letter);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Or (for String 's') `        return s.length() != s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size();`